# ImageBackground: Element type is invalid

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've got this issue. As you can see, I've already export (with redux) the Component. What did I do wrong?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nvDX.png)

```
...

const Principal = (props) => {
    return (

        <ImageBackground   style={{flex : 1}} source={bg} >
            <View style={styles.topo}>
              <Text style={styles.txtTopo}>
                WhatsApp Clone!
              </Text> 
            </View>

            <View style={styles.centro}>
              <TextInput value={props.email} onChangeText={ (value) => props.modificaEmail(value) } style={{fontSize: 20, height: 45}} placeholder='E-mail'/>
              <TextInput secureTextEntry value={props.senha} onChangeText = { (value) => props.modificaSenha(value) } style={{fontSize: 20, height: 45}} placeholder='Senha'/>

              <TouchableHighlight  onPress={() => Actions.Cadastrar()} activeOpacity={0.3} underlayColor='#F5FCFF'>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>Ainda não tem cadastro? Cadastre-se </Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.bottom}>
              <Button title='Entrar' color='#115E54' onPress={() => false} />
            </View>
        </ImageBackground>
    );

}

...

const mapStateToProps = (state) => (
  {
    email: state.AutenticacaoReducer.email,
    senha: state.AutenticacaoReducer.senha
  }
)

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { modificaEmail, modificaSenha })(Principal);
```

I've googled it, but unsuccessfully, so, can you guys help me?

Comment: Just type error in your question instead of uploading it as an image.

Comment: The problem is probably in the import ststements that you didn't include:  maybe import xxx instead of import { xxx }. Can you post the entire file, including the import statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is telling that you are using some object which is **undefined**. So below are possibilities that you need to look on:

```
props.email  
props.senha
```

You can be getting undefined in one of them or both of them. You can just `console` the `props`. So you can get the idea about it.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(props));
```

You can add **height** and **width**.

Hope it will help you!!!

Comment: The console don't return undefided! It's all ok

My dependencies
`"dependencies": {
  "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
  "react-native": "0.44.0",
  "react-native-router-flux": "^3.39.1",
  "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
  "redux": "^3.7.2"`

Comment: If I use Image instead of ImageBackground, all works, but the image don't appear. Just crashes when I'm using ImageBackground

Comment: Try give height and width. And then check for image.

Comment: Giving height and width works with Image, but with ImageBackground still the same. But, thanks, I will use Image with this version of React-native.

Comment: Cool. I update my answer as well. You can upvote if its helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

@Rahamin seems on the money. Try

```
const PrincipalComponent = connect(mapStateToProps, { modificaEmail, modificaSenha })(Principal);

export {
  PrincipalComponent as Principal
};
```

Then

```
import { Principal } from './Principal';
```

Comment: Still the same :/

My dependencies
`"dependencies": {
  "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
  "react-native": "0.44.0",
  "react-native-router-flux": "^3.39.1",
  "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
  "redux": "^3.7.2"`

Comment: If I use Image instead of ImageBackground, all works, but the image don't appear. Just crashes when I'm using ImageBackground